# Show future entries / parent relationship

Tags: relationships, related-entries, reverse-related-entries

I have a channels "Show" and "Event".
The Event channel has a relationship field (rel_show) to link to a Show

In the Show detail page.. i want to show all the Event related to that Show (event the upcoming events)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="show" url_title="{last_segment}"}
LOTS OF CODE... 
{parents field="rel_show" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" show_futures_entries="yes"}
MORE CODE ...  
{/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

2 questions..

1. The show_future_entries doesn't work is there a way to bypass or make it work
2. I need to group the event by Year.. but i think relationship doesn't allow that right?!.. I can use php to "group" or put and Header when the loop dectect a new Year..

I also may close the "show" exp:channel:entries.. to open a new one with channel="event" and then use a if statement to check if related entries is the good show.. But i have a looootttt of event..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My bad!

```
show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"
```

works.. i miss typed  futures -> future.. 
I'll figure it out  about the "heading"